# Can "without abandonment" mean "with abandon"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

An author I'm currently reading often uses language in a slightly irregular fashion. I've been trying to decide if it's playful and intentional, which would be intriguing. If it's not intentional, then it's either an error on the author's part (fine) or on the editor's (less fine).

The current book includes the following (presumably wrong) phrase, in a scene where two people try to elude others.

"Without abandonment, she grabbed my hand and pulled me down the pavement"

Given the nature of the scene, I think it's supposed to mean "with abandon" but that doesn't totally fit. The only other guess I have is something along the lines of "without hesitation".

In this context, I think the phrase is used as a state of mind decriptor, not a literal one. Has anyone ever heard the phrase "without abandonment" used in this way?

Comment: Sounds humorous to me.  Because she did *not* abandon you she took you with her.  So it’s a play on the “normal” ‘with abandon’ phrase.

Comment: Do you mean 'with abandon'?

Comment: What is the author's first language? If not English, perhaps they sometimes use English words which are false friends of words in their native language, and perhaps "abandonment" is one of these.

Comment: I would generally take "without abandonment" to mean roughly "tenaciously", though that sense seems a bit "off" in the above quote.

Comment: I will note that "without abandonment" is a term in maritime law.

Answer (score 1):

They do not have opposite meanings, and yet they not synonyms either.

The noun [**abandonment**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/abandonment) means leaving something or someone behind.

The noun [**abandon**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/abandon) means lack of restraint: it's about someone's *manner* or *behaviour*.

The sentence

> Without abandonment, she grabbed my hand and pulled me down the pavement

is a tautology; she is not leaving the speaker behind.

Answer (score 0):

It should be with abandon as in abandoning all care or inhibitions. Common 2nd language mistake. In this case though I think the writer was trying to say without leaving him or her there.

Answer (score 0):

> In this **context**, I think the phrase is used as a state of mind descriptor, not a literal one.

Unfortunately, you seem to have omitted the actual context of the narrative and the source.

If "with abandon" is, approximately, "with no regard for the consequences" then, if the author is playing with words, "without abandonment" = **intentionally and purposefully**.

With context it might be a clever reference to the marine insurance use of abandonment, such that "without abandonment" would mean "not relinquishing ownership of me."